# If else control terminated with out go back to previous control java

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, logic, ujmp

I have two data file one is for Robot odometry dataset and another one is robot sensor data set. I just show a portion of those two file.
  Robot odometer

```
Time     forward velocity     angular velocity
12.560000   0.067000            0.000000
12.580000   0.067000            0.000000
12.600000   0.067000            0.000000
12.620000   0.067000            0.000000
12.640000   0.067000            0.000000
12.660000   0.067000            0.000000
12.680000   0.033500            0.000000
12.700000   0.067000            0.000000
12.720000   0.067000            0.000000
12.740000   0.067000            0.000000
12.760000   0.067000            0.000000
12.780000   0.067000            0.000000
12.800000   0.067000            0.000000
```

Sensor Data set

```
Time        CNo:     Range      Bearing
12.720000 90.000000 2.148000    0.025000
```

Now, After analysis this data set we can see that 8th(starting from 0) data of odometer data is same as sensor data.

In my program I construct a Omega matrix which add -1 in the off diagonal and +1 in the diagonal of each xt,xt-1 timestamp of corresponding row and column. When it encounter the same timestamp in sensor data set, it fixed a row for this data and update this row and corresponding column of odometer data set. I choose the last row(row no. 13) where I incorporate sensor measurement data. And update that column where this measurement data timestamp same as odometer data(Column No:8).

My code

```
import org.ujmp.core.Matrix;
import org.ujmp.core.SparseMatrix;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test9 {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Matrix Bigomega=Matrix.Factory.zeros(14,14);
    Matrix omega = SparseMatrix.Factory.zeros(14, 14);
    int i = 0, i1 = 0, k1 = 0, k2 = 0,l=0,l1=0;
    double[] timex = new double[14];
    double[] forwardx = new double[14];
    double[] angularx = new double[14];
    double[]x1=new double[14];
    double[]y1=new double[14];
    double[]theta1=new double[14];
    double []landx=new double[1];
    double[]landy=new double[1];
    double[] timeya = new double[1];
    double[] codea = new double[1];
    double[] rangea = new double[1];
    double[] bearinga = new double[1];
    Scanner x = new Scanner(new File("/home/froboticscse/IdeaProjects/UJMPtest/src/main/java/rtest.txt"));
    Scanner y = new Scanner(new File("/home/froboticscse/IdeaProjects/UJMPtest/src/main/java/mtese.txt"));



        while (x.hasNext()) {

            double time = x.nextDouble();
            double forward = x.nextDouble();
            double angular = x.nextDouble();
            timex[i] = time;
            forwardx[i] = forward;
            angularx[i] = angular;
            x1[i] = ((forwardx[i] * 0.006 + Math.cos(0 + (angularx[i] * 0.006) / 2)));
            y1[i] = ((forwardx[i] * 0.006 + Math.sin(0 + (angularx[i] * 0.006) / 2)));
            theta1[i] = (angularx[i] * 0.006);
            i++;
        }

        while (y.hasNext()) {
            double timey = y.nextDouble();
            double code = y.nextDouble();
            double range = y.nextDouble();
            double bearing = y.nextDouble();
            timeya[i1] = timey;
            codea[i1] = code;
            rangea[i1] = range;
            bearinga[i1] = bearing;

            i1++;

        }
        while (k1 < timex.length && k2 < timeya.length) {
            if (timex[k1] < timeya[k2]) {
                omega.setAsDouble(1, k1, k1);
                omega.setAsDouble(-1, k1, k1 + 1);
                omega.setAsDouble(-1,k1+1,k1);
                omega.setAsDouble(1,k1+1,k1+1);
                Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
                omega.clear();
                k1++;
                l++;

            }


            else if (timex[k1] == timeya[k2]) {
                omega.setAsDouble(1, k1, k1);
                omega.setAsDouble(-1, k1, k1 + 1);
                omega.setAsDouble(-1,k1+1,k1);
                omega.setAsDouble(1,k1+1,k1+1);
                Bigomega=Bigomega.plus(omega);
                omega.clear();

                if (codea[k2] == 90.0) {

                    omega.setAsDouble(1,k1,k1);
                    omega.setAsDouble(-1, 13, k1);
                    omega.setAsDouble(1,13,13);
                    omega.setAsDouble(-1, k1, 13);
                   }

                Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
                omega.clear();
                BigXi=BigXi.plus(Xi);
                Xi.clear();
                k2++;
                l1++;

                }

                }
    System.out.println(Bigomega);
    }


}
```

My output is:

```
1.0000    -1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
-1.0000     2.0000    -1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
0.0000    -1.0000     2.0000    -1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
0.0000     0.0000    -1.0000     2.0000    -1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
0.0000     0.0000     0.0000    -1.0000     2.0000    -1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000    -1.0000     2.0000    -1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000    -1.0000     2.0000    -1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000    -1.0000     2.0000    -1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000    -1.0000     3.0000    -1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000    -1.0000
0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000    -1.0000     1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000    -1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000
```

If you compare two data file you  can see that odometer data 8th row is same with sensor data row. My program say that if timestamp of odometer data less than(initialize counter k1) timestamp of sensor data `do this`. If the timestamp of odometer data==  timestamp of sensor data(k2 loop counter initialize) `do that`. After equal to statement execute k2 loop counter increment then the statement again come into < decision. So after execution of 8th row as per logic

```
 if (timex[k1] < timeya[k2]) {
                omega.setAsDouble(1, k1, k1);
                omega.setAsDouble(-1, k1, k1 + 1);
                omega.setAsDouble(-1,k1+1,k1);
                omega.setAsDouble(1,k1+1,k1+1);
                Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
                omega.clear();
```

Execute. But the control never go back to this block rather it was terminated.

I cannot find out any logical flaw. But cannot understand why the control terminated. It should go back to if statement.

Comment: Have you tried to unit test your code? Advice: refactor your code in small functions, it is definitely easier to test and find your bug. If I were you, I would try in debug-mode.

Comment: Yes I tried to debug with a small code block. Same error occur

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your code? I mean, what is your overall goal? Can you explain with a pseudo-code?

Comment: I modify code here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51652975/logical-error-in-if-else-statement-in-java?noredirect=1#comment90269208_51652975